# reportlab set left table position

Tags: reportlab

How can I set the left position of a table?

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % pdf_name
buffer = StringIO()
PAGESIZE = pagesizes.portrait(pagesizes.A4)
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer, pagesize=PAGESIZE, leftMargin=1*cm)
story = []

story.append(Paragraph(header_part2, styleN))
table_row = ['Total Score:','']
data.append(table_row)
ts = [
    #header style    
    ('LINEABOVE', (0,0), (-1,0), 1, colors.gray),
    ('LINEBELOW', (0,0), (-1,0), 1, colors.gray)]
t = Table(data, (6*cm,6*cm), None, style=ts)
    story.append(t)
    doc.build(story)
    pdf = buffer.getvalue()
buffer.close()
response.write(pdf)
```

Whereas the paragraph is printed one cm from the left, table is printed with almost no distance to the left page border.

Where do I have to set the leftMargin for the table position?

The same is valid for images I add. They seem to be printed somewhere.

```
story.append(Image(path,35,10))
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found the magic hAlign keyword:

```
t = Table(data, (6*cm,6*cm,2*cm,2*cm,2*cm), None, style=ts, hAlign='LEFT')
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add that you can also set the alignment in TableStyle just like you set the *lineabove* and *linebelow*.

While this may not be valuable information in itself, it is important to know that horizontal alignment is set with **keyword 'ALIGN' and not 'HALIGN'** (as you would easily assume given that vertical alignment is set with *'VALIGN'* and the above solution also has hAlign in the function call). I went mad trying to align stuff with 'HALIGN' all day.

Below is a code sample where you can test the horizontal alignment ('ALIGN').

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.platypus.tables import Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib import colors

doc = SimpleDocTemplate('align.pdf', showBoundary=1)

t = Table((('', 'Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C', 'Team D'),
   ('Quarter 1', 100, 200, 300, 400),
   ('Quarter 2', 200, 400, 600, 800),
   ('Total', 300, 600, 900, 1200)),
  (72, 45, 45, 45, 45),
  (25, 15, 15, 15)
  )

t.setStyle(TableStyle([
   ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'RIGHT'),
   ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.red, None, (2, 2, 1)),
   ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.blue),
   ]))

story = [t]
doc.build(story)
```

[image: Resulting table in pdf]